# AngularJS Table row span

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, ng-grid, ngtable

How to do a row span in bootstrap table with Angular JS?  My table is created using ng-repeat.
With ng-repeat I think it is not possible. So I look at ng-grid and ng-table, both have  grouping.
but they  create a collapsible column. not exactly a row span. so please let me know my options.

I am trying to achieve  like:

```
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
</tr>   
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>

        <td>Smith2</td> 
        <td>60</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>            
        <td>Smith3</td> 
        <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td> 
      <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1VBQGVoamQbqv9uYmnWB?p=preview

But it is not a static data, it will be a list of object from server.
Any help appreciated

Comment: To add `rowspan` to your JSON is coupling your server side to your client concepts. What if you want to consume this JSON on a device? Yeah, a JSON property can be ignored, but we have ugly code there. An alternative option might be to use [`ng-repeat-first`](https://robteix.com/blog/2014/11/22/multi-level-tables-in-angularjs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a rowspan property to your JSON. Like:

```
myJson = [{attr1:'foo', attr2:'bar',rowspan:2},{attr1:'foo', attr2:'bar',rowspan:0}];
```

Then you can use both `ng-if` and `rowspan` like this:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-if="item.rowspan>0" rowspan="{{item.rowspan}}">{{item.attr1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.attr2}}</td>
<tr>
```

You can iterate through the JSON and add the `rowspan` conditionally:

```
data.forEach(function(item){
    if(someCondition){
        item.rowspan = 2; // or 0, 1, 2, 3...
    }
});
```

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/48yDXfOWEGOBcnrUyRk7?p=preview).

Comment: Hi, Can you add plunkr,if you don't mind. Also in my case if I don't have control over the JSON response from the server, then any other options ?

Comment: Hi, is it possible to do row span on multiple columns